# MySQL select from tables with relationship without join

Tags: mysql, select, join, relationship

I have several tables and related them to each other. (MySQL Workbench 1:1 Non-Identifying Relationship)

[image]

Now I want to read the out in the query, without join.
Is this even posible?

Comment: Using sub query it is possible

Comment: You can read them as (Select * from table1, table2 and so on..). Do you  mean this?

Comment: What do you mean by "read the out in the query"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to read from the user, information and Addresses table row. The best way to work with SELECT * FROM user information, Addresses WHERE Users.User_TOKEN  = "*" .Without specially with the join conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be :

```
SELECT u.*, ui.*, a.* 
FROM Users u, Users_Info ui, Addresses a
WHERE u.Users_UInfo_TOKEN = ui.UInfo_TOKEN
AND ui.UInfo_Address_TOKEN = a.Address_TOKEN
```

Comment: this is similar (if not slower) to JOIN